# How to extract text between html tags from pandas DataFrame to new column?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm trying to extract code from text corpus.

I have now something like this

```
input = pd.DataFrame([[0, "Line 0 some text before <pre> line 0 some code </pre> line 0 some text after"],\
                     [1, "Line 1 some text before <pre> line 1 some code </pre> line 1 some text after"]
                    ], columns = ["id", "body"])
# result = SomeFunctions(input)
result = pd.DataFrame([[0, "Line 0 some text before line 0 some text after", "line 0 some code"],\
                     [1, "Line 0 some text before line 1 some text after", "line 1 some code"]
                    ], columns = ["id", "text", "code"])
```

(result is what I want to get after, SomeFunctions is what I need).
What is the best way to do this?
I have about 3Gb corpus containing ~1.2M records.

Comment: may be try sometihing like `df.join(input_['body'].str.split('<.*?>',expand=True))` but general idea is split the string and expand it

Comment: Is there always one and only one `<pre></pre>` tag per line?

Comment: @Roman see my attempt. Happy to clarify if you needed me to

Answer (score 0):

For a large body of text, I suspect Unix tools are fastest. For your example:

```
input_ = pd.DataFrame([[0, "Line 0 some text before <pre> line 0 some code </pre> line 0 some text after"],\
                     [1, "Line 1 some text before <pre> line 1 some code </pre> line 1 some text after"]
                    ], columns = ["id", "body"])

input_.to_csv('input.csv', header=None)
```

(You shouldn't name objects in Python `input`, as it's a reserved name.)

Then in your shell:

```
sed -n "/<.*>/s/<.*>//p" in.csv > 1.csv
grep -oP "(?<=\>).*(?=<)"  in.csv > 2.csv
# uses -P for perl regex, so needs gnu grep
# on OSX do `brew install grep` and use ggrep instead of grep
paste -d ',' 1.csv 2.csv > result.csv
```

Then in Python:

```
result = pd.read_csv('result.csv', header=None, names=["id", "text", "code"])
```

Comment: Hi, Josh, thank you, this works fine. But you guessed right, I have multiple <pre> tags (I didn't know this today morning). Could you help me to adopt this?
Also I wonder if <.*> means exactly <pre> or it's any html tag?

Comment: Do you want to include all HTML, or only pre? And if there are multiple tags, do you want them all together in one column, or one column per tag?

Comment: Only <pre>. There are some other tags but I want to leave it as it is.
The best is text in <pre>... </pre> in first column, all other in second.

Comment: Maybe add this to your sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
#Split df['body'] by the whitespace before </pre>

    df=input
    df3=df.body.str.split('\s+(?=\<\/[a-z]+\>)', expand=True)
    df3

#Replace the text between <> with nothing

    df3[0]=df3[0].str.replace(r'<pre>', '', regex=False)
    df3[1]=df3[1].str.replace(r'</pre> ','',regex=True)

#Rename columns
df3.columns=['text','code']
df3
```

Comment: Looks like both solutions with re are suitable for me, thank you (and also Josh Friedlander). Could you help me to adopt this for multiple <pre> </pre> tags please? I'm new with regular expressions.
I want two columns, one with all non-tagged text and second with inside <pre> tag